# Cannot run Dmg Files for Xamarin and XCode in OS X El Capitan Virtual Machine

Tags: ios, xamarin

So my problem is, that none of the DMG Files i need on an OS X VM are working. I need the OS X VM for Xamarin IOS , so im trying to install XCode and Xamarin on it. Every dmg. File i try to run looks like this:

[image]

What could be the reason for this? Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Processor and Ram:

Intel i5-2500k Processor
6gb ram

The Vm Player is VMPlayer7.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer myself , it was just a visual problem. Just click when opened the Window on "View" -> As List and the items will be shown.